# Problems compiling Rivet package due to yaml-cpp build

Tags: compilation, yaml, yaml-cpp

I am having difficulties compiling the Rivet package due to my yaml-cpp build.
I have installed the other various things needed without much hassle but then when I run:

```
./configure --with-boost=/Users/jackmedley/Desktop/boost_1_52_0
```

I get the error:

```
....
checking for fastjet/D0RunIIConePlugin.hh... yes
checking fastjet/TrackJetPlugin.hh usability... yes
checking fastjet/TrackJetPlugin.hh presence... yes
checking for fastjet/TrackJetPlugin.hh... yes
configure: Found yaml-cpp library at /usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.a
configure: Found yaml-cpp header directory at /usr/local/include
checking yaml-cpp/node.h usability... no
checking yaml-cpp/node.h presence... no
checking for yaml-cpp/node.h... no
checking yaml-cpp/node/node.h usability... no
checking yaml-cpp/node/node.h presence... no
checking for yaml-cpp/node/node.h... no
configure: error: yaml-cpp API version could not be determined
```

Has anybody else had similar problems?